# Text Bold with fontspec

Tags: fonts, fontspec, bold, italic

I am trying to use:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
```

But I cannot manage to emphasise the text by using usual `\textbf` or `\textit`. How to do it on Mac? Or which is the closest to Cambria\Calibri default LaTeX font?

Comment: Are you using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: I use XeLaTex .

Comment: You should look at the `.log` if you are unable to get bold or italics for an installed font.

Comment: It works for me too, maybe you haven't installed the proper fonts? You need to install the Family (regular, bold, italics, and bold italics), not just the regular font.

Comment: You comment on Mico's [answer below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244336/9077) that it now works, but Mico is only doing what say you also say you are doing. The reason why you didn't get it to work must therefore be that you did something wrong (typos or something). I'm therefore voting to close.

Answer (score 4):

(I run MacTeX2015 on a MacBookPro running MacOSX 10.10.3 "Yosemite".)

I would load the `Cambria` and `Calibri` fonts via `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont` instructions. The program runs equally well under XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Calibri}
\newcommand\test{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\begin{document}

\test

\textbf{\test}

\textit{\test}

\textbf{\textit{\test}}

\medskip\sffamily

\test

\textbf{\test}

\textit{\test}

\textbf{\textit{\test}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This isn't doing anything different from what the OP is claiming to have tried. Since this now works, it must mean that the OP must have done something wrong (which we can't know since no MWE was posted). I'm therefore voting to close.